# Leak in Maytag washer

Tags: leak, washing-machine

I have a Maytag stackable washer which leaks a little water after each load. The leak is coming from the bottom of that plastic reservoir in the lower right hand of the picture. That is connected to the belt. It only starts leaking a couple of minutes after the load ended.
Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That item you have circled, is the drain pump. If it is leaking, the rubber gasket/o-ring inside could be bad. If it comes apart easy, you might be able to get a replacement gasket/o-ring. If it does not come apart, you will need to replace the pump.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to replace the whole pump. I appreciate your assistance!